# Django ORM query for this purpose

Tags: python, django, ajax, django-orm

I'm displaying rows of my **Influencer** objects in some view. Any of those influencers can be in a  **InfluencerList** object (related by many-to-many). I have added an "Add to List" button to each row so user can add influencers to his own lists (user and influencer list are related by many-to-one). When user clicks the button a popup window opens and it displays users all list names and each lists influencer count next to it.

Here is what i got so far: https://pasteboard.co/IMHHSa6.png

What i want to do is make some of those checkboxes checked by default if any of those lists contains the related influencer. Here is my current code:

**models.py:**

```
class Influencer(models.Model):
    # fields are not included for clarity
    pass

class InfluencerList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField('Name:', max_length=20, blank=False)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='lists')
    influencers = models.ManyToManyField('Influencer', related_name='lists')
```

**views.py:**

```
class InfluencerListView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    model = Influencer
    # template_name = "app1/influencer_list.html"
    context_object_name = 'influencers' # not necessary, default is object_list
    #queryset = Influencer.objects.all()

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        logged_in_user = self.request.user
        context['myLists'] = logged_in_user.lists.values('name').annotate(
        influencers_count=Count('influencers'))    # returns a list of dicts
        return context
```

**views.py**

```
{% for myList in myLists %}
    <label class="list_existing_item">
        <input class="checkbox-input" id="myCheckbox" type="checkbox" 
        data-inf_id="{{influencer.id}}" data-list_id="{{myList.id}}"
        onclick="myFunc(this)">
        {{myList.name}}
        <span class="list_count"> {{myList.influencers_count}}  </span>                        
    </label>
{% endfor %}
```

I know i must pass the information about which influencer belongs to which list so i tryed this query:

```
context['myLists'] = logged_in_user.lists.values('name','influencers').annotate(
influencers_count=Count('influencers')
```

But it returns a queryset like this, which doesn't allow me to use count or iterate through list and create my html elements:

```
QuerySet [<br>
{'name': 'list1', 'influencers': 2222, 'influencers_count': 1},<br> 
{'name': 'list1', 'influencers': 2345, 'influencers_count': 1}, <br>
{'name': 'List123', 'influencers': 2222, 'influencers_count': 1}, <br>
{'name': 'list2', 'influencers': None, 'influencers_count': 0}
]
```

It would be very nice for me to have a query  which returns those first two dics with `'influencers_count':2`
For my later purposes I also read some AJAX tutorials on how can i add or delete my influencers to individiual lists by just checking or unchecking the checkboxes, but i guess i don't know where to search for it... First things first, i hate spaghetti code and i want to accomplish those requirements in a proper way, thanks for any help or advices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply drop the `.values(..)` here. Then it will return `InfluencerList` objects, with an extra attribute `influencers_count`:

```
# no .values(..)
context['myLists'] = logged_in_user.lists.annotate(
    influencers_count=Count('influencers')
)
```

In general it is better *not* to use `.values(..)` *unless* you for example need to perform a GROUP BY on something different than the model over which you span the query. But that is *not* the case here.

Comment: thank you for your answer, as a newbie i tought that using .values optimize performance as less columns are included. I will appreciate if you could give me some guidelines in order to add and remove objects by using just the checkboxes.

Comment: @IbrahimAkar: usually then it is better to use `.only(..)` or `.defer(..)`. But usually it does not matter that much anyway. Selecting extra columns will normally not have that much impact. Only if these columns contain huge amounts of data (like an XML stream, etc.), it is better to exclude those.